# How to store array in node red context

Tags: javascript, node-red

I'm trying to store and get back array in Node Red context (or flow) object.

I do this to store, can see output message with array:

```
var acstate=[];
for(var i=0;i<15;i++){
     acstate[i]=1;
    }
context.set("acstate",acstate);
msg={'payload':acstate};
return msg;
```

This node to get array from context:

```
var acstate=[];
acstate = context.get('acstate');
for(var i=0;i<15;i++){
     node.warn(acstate[i]);
    }
msg={'payload':acstate};
return msg;
```

It shows

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
```

Can't find info about storing arrays, is it possible with context? If not, what can I use to keep data?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible that the node reading the array from the context can get triggered before the one that writes it to the context. If so you need to add a test to see if the `context.get()` returns `undefined` (as it will if it's not been set yet)

Comment: Instead of assuming there are 15 elements, use acstate.length

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that I'm trying to write to context and to read from context from different nodes. So now I tried to change "context" to "flow" and it works! Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can write like

```
var acstate=[];
var temp = context.get('acstate');

for(var x=0;x<temp.length;x++){
     acstate.push(temp[x]);
    }

for(var i=0;i<15;i++){
     node.warn(acstate[i]);
    }
msg={'payload':acstate};
return msg;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create the array before assigning it to the return from another function:

```
    var acstate; /* =[] NOT REQUIRED; */
    acstate = context.get('acstate');

    if ( typeof acstate == "object" 
    && typeof acstate.length == "number"
    && acstate.length > 0 ) {
        for(var i=0;i<acstate.length; i++){
           node.warn(acstate[i]);
        }
    }
    msg={'payload':acstate};
    return msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't mention that I'm trying to write to context and to read from context from different nodes. Looks like each node has it's own context, thats why data stored in context of one node is not available in context of another node. So now I tried to change "context" to "flow" and it works!

```
var temp = flow.get('acstate');
```

Thank you for answers!